# Name convention over a Rails Migration reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration, generator

i have a problem creating a db table through rails generators.

I named a table personal_data and works fine.

```
class CreatePersonalData < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :personal_data do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :lastName
    t.string :dni
    t.string :contact
    t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

But i created another table with a reference to Personal Data

```
class CreateMerchants < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :merchants do |t|
    t.string :storeName
    t.references :personal_data, index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.references :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.string :webPage
    t.string :city

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

And when a run the migration instead of seeking for personal_data_id the migrations looks for personal_datum_id and throws and exception.

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  no existe la columna «personal_datum_id» referida en la llave foránea
>   : ALTER TABLE "merchants" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e4239c30dc"
>   FOREIGN KEY ("personal_datum_id")
>     REFERENCES "personal_data" ("id")

I translate the error to English

> column "personal_datum_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Comment: @Davit It seems that this is the way Rails work. Table name is plural. It seems to say that `data` is plural and `datum` is singular. So when I search for an id, it goes for `personal_datum_id`. I guess if the table name is personal_datas, it will be no error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it's confused, but perhaps you can set up your inflections such that the plural of personal_data is personal_data?

In the file: config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'personal_data', 'personal_data'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

add `self.table_name = 'personal_data'` in your personal_data.rb model and run the migration